# UISearchBarController "works", but doesn't display on screen

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, filter, uisearchbar

I have a CoreData project written in Swift that I've added a `UISearchController` to. I set breakpoints to see if the search is working and I can print out a list of `filteredObjects` from `lldb` in the console, but they don't display on the view.

Basically, the cells in my app load fine when the the `searchBar` isn't in use, but the moment I type something in the `searchBar`, I've verified the `searchPredicate`'s being set and objects are being added to my `filteredObjects` array, but I can't figure out why they're not going on the screen. I think my problem "lives" here:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    if searchPredicate == nil {
        self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    } else {
        // configure the cell based on filteredObjects data
        if let note = self.filteredObjects?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = note.noteTitle
    }
    return cell
}
```

If there's no predicate, it's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is returning what it finds in the `managedObjectContext`. If there IS a `searchPredicate`, I need to return a the info from the `Note` object in the `filteredObjects` array from the `searchResultsController`.

I think I know "what" I need to do, but I don't know the "how" part. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. Thanks for reading. If you've got any ideas, I would be grateful.

Here's my `Note` object:

```
class Note: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var dateCreated: NSDate
    @NSManaged var dateEdited: NSDate
    @NSManaged var noteTitle: String
    @NSManaged var noteBody: String

}
```

Another potential "problem area" could be my `configureCell` method:

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("noteTitle")!.description
}
```

I've got the `numberOfRowsInSection` set here:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.searchPredicate == nil {
        let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as! NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    } else {
        return filteredObjects?.count ?? 0
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant properties I've got setup and the `viewDidLoad`:

```
    class MasterViewController: UITableViewController,
 NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate,
 UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate

// Properties
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

// Properties for UISearchController
var searchController: UISearchController!
var searchPredicate: NSPredicate?
var filteredObjects : [Note]? = nil
```

Here's my `viewDidLoad:`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
        self.detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }

    // UISearchController setup
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.delegate = self               
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController?.searchBar
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

This delegate method gets called when the search bar's text the search bar becomes first responder.

```
// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate Method
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchText = self.searchController?.searchBar.text // steve put breakpoint
    println(searchController.searchBar.text)
    if let searchText = searchText {
        searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "noteBody contains[c] %@", searchText)
        filteredObjects = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.filter() {
            return self.searchPredicate!.evaluateWithObject($0)
            } as! [Note]?
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        println(searchPredicate)
    }
}
```

When the `searchBar` is cancelled, everything goes back to normal when I use this delegate method to set the `searchPredicate` & `filteredObjects` back to nil

```
// MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate methods    
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        updateSearchResultsForSearchController(self.searchController)
    }

    func didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        println("didDismissSearchController")
        self.searchPredicate = nil
        self.filteredObjects = nil
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: What does happen when you start searching?  Do the existing cells disappear?  Do any cells load (even empty ones)?  Does it throw an error?

Comment: The existing cells disappear when the `searchBar` is clicked, no errors are thrown, app runs without crashing. I put a few breakpoints in to stop it mid-execution. There are objects in the `filteredObjects` array and the `searchPredicate` is set, but the cells don't update on screen.

Comment: Check the value of `filteredObjects?.count ?? 0` in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method.  And in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, try setting `cell.textLabel.text = "Test title"` and see if anything appears.

Comment: nothing's comes up when I set the cellForRowAtIndexPath as `cell.textLabel.text = "Test title"`. Here's the repo. I'm out of ideas. I'm either the first or the dumbest to try to do this, most likely the latter. https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/blocnotes/commits/add-pull-down-search-bar-take-6

Comment: Well, I pasted your code into my test app.  I had to tweak a few `as!` to `as` because I'm using Xcode 6.1.1, and change the NSManagedObject names to match my model.  But it works fine.  So rest assured, you're not dumb - something weird is going on.  First off, try cleaning your build (in the menu, Project -> Clean) and recompile.

Comment: I cleaned the cache the "old fashioned" way :) `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache`. I just need to figure out how to configure the cell to display the `filteredObjects` array. That's where I'm having trouble.